# How to make bootstrap multiple tab group that shares same ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

First of all I understand that there should not be multiple instance of same ID but I am looking for better solution that will help me to complete my requirement. Below is just an example of what I am trying to do:

```
<div class="tab-group-1">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a href="#abc1" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#abc2" data-toggle="tab">About</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="abc1">Home tab content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="abc2">About tab content</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="tab-group-2">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a href="#abc1" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#abc2" data-toggle="tab">About</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="abc1">Home tab content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="abc2">About tab content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: By clicking for example `About` tab, you want the content and active tab to change on both?

Comment: Here is a fiddle to demonstrate the issue : http://www.bootply.com/Jd9IFHDcts ....
But normally, ID must be unique after W3C

Comment: So what exactly do you want it to do? You've provided some code that works perfectly in my opinion.

Comment: @shadowfox Just look fine the fiddle. As you can see, every tab you click, is affecting the first tab group, not the second....

Comment: Again, that behavior is perfectly normal.
You're telling your tab-button to target #abc, ID's are supposed to be unique so it targets first encounter.

Now, what exactly do you want it to do? Because the fix is simple, give other ID. Instead of both naming them #abc, call them #group1-abc and #group2-abc?

Comment: @Shadowfox thanks for the fiddle, but as pointed by ~pbanard "every tab you click, is affecting the first tab group, not the second". ~urbz hope now it's clear about requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Here is something but you have small changes :

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/U0LkomjCne

**Explain** : change `a[href]` by `a[data-target]` and prefix the target with the wrapper class.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="tab-group-1">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a data-target=".tab-group-1 #abc1" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-target=".tab-group-1 #abc2" data-toggle="tab">About</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="abc1">Home tab content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="abc2">About tab content</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-group-2">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a data-target=".tab-group-2 #abc1" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-target=".tab-group-2 #abc2" data-toggle="tab">About</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="abc1">Home tab content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="abc2">About tab content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this sounds like ultimate solution, thanks. Is there a way I don't refer the parent class `tab-group-1` and `tab-group-2`. I understand this need to scoped/namespaces  but it needs to be modular `this tab`

Comment: Great example.
I was cloning the content from my page and passing into a bootbox dialog (hence the duplicate IDs). I used    data-target=".modal #userDetails" href="#"   to target only the tab in the open modal